# idiom for warning someone who has entered a place without permission or invitation?

Tags: idioms

Suppose that you are in your room. suddenly someone enters your room without permission. Is there a term or idiom which means "It is wrong 
 to enter a place without permission and invitation" ? (You want to blame him/her for entering the place without permission and invitation)

We use this in our mother tongue: Here is not a stable so that you cannot enter here without permission.

Comment: "sb" is not a word

Comment: "Beware (all) ye who enter (here)!"

Comment: The two answers posted below prove your question is not clear. Now, is it an idiom in your native language to say "Here is not stable so that..."? Is it used only when someone enters your room without permission? Then, don't you think it would be enough to say "it's bad manners/impolite/wrong to enter a room without knocking"?

Comment: "*Abandon all hope...*"

Comment: @Drew That one might be a little too strong. :)

Comment: In all seriousness though "*This is a restricted area/floor/room (or you are not permitted here), please leave (immediately) and do not come back (here again).*" sounds like a firm yet polite way to handle those kind of situations.

Comment: "Ever heard of _knocking_?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hey, don't come barging in [just barge in] as though [as if] you owned the place.**

[*barge in*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/barge-in)

> to walk into a room quickly, without being invited

*[as if you owned the place](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/as-if-you-owned-the-place?q=as%20if%20%20you%20%20owned%20the%20place)*

> in a way that is too confident: *He walked into the office as if he owned the place.*

Both of these definitions are from the Cambridge Dictionary.

The sarcastic approach mentioned in a comment, "Every heard of knocking?" is pretty good too, but it's more of a comment.  My suggestion is more assertive and clear that you don't want the person to barge in again.

Answer (score 1):

In American English you can say [No Trespassing](https://www.google.com/amp/www.macmillandictionary.com/license/amp/dictionary/british/no-trespassing?)

("used on signs to warn people not to enter a place or area"–MacMillan)

to warn  someone who  is in the process of trespassing not to do it again. You could also say

> Don't come in my room without my permission. Now get out and don't come in here again (without my permission).

But all that can be compressed into 'No trespassing' because by saying this, you are telling them

A. They are in the process of trespassing
B. It's wrong for them to be trespassing
C. Warning them  not to do it again

It's kind of difficult to find language without more details as to your situation: where are you (at home,  at university), who is the intruder (your little sibling, a neighbor,  a weirdo, an ex), what is the 'intruder' doing, are they breaking the law, do you feel threatened, etc.

Leftover from answer to the first edition of your question:

You can search Google for images of [No Trespassing signs](https://www.google.com/search?q=no+trespassing+signs)

You can also add other verbiage if you choose, such as

No entry. Keep out. Violators will be prosecuted. (This property protected by shotgun five days a week, and I'm not saying which days.)

Comment: I didnt mean this. After somebody enters your room, you cant tell him/her no trespassing. I want an idiom which shows  that you didn't like this action. I mean to blame. So that he/she won't enter a place without permission anymore

Answer (score 1):

For stronger terms, try:

**No Entry**, **Private Property**, **Keep Out**.

For milder ones, you could us:

**Do not disturb**, or **Please knock and wait**.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "***who goes there?***" is used by security personnel to challenge unexpected visitors/trespassers and is equivalent to *warning someone not to enter a place without permission*.

Macmillan:

> **[who goes there?](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/who-goes-there)**
>   *PHRASE SPOKEN*
>
> used by a soldier guarding a place for asking who is coming towards
>   them

ODO:

> **[who goes there?](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/who_goes_there%3F)**
>   *PHRASE*
>
> Said by a sentry as a challenge.
>
> ‘Three hundred metres further on Police Superintendent John Trott
>   halted the marchers by standing in the roadway and calling ‘who goes
>   there?’’
>   ‘‘Halt, who goes there?’ yelled the larger of the men at
>   arms that stood atop the large wall.’